# c variable turning into -17918 when incremented

Tags: c, arrays, variables, gameboy

hi i am making a programming language that will run on the nintendo gameboy in c
which is why you will see some functions like waitpad(); 
but this question is unrelated the the gameboy librarys
for some reason when ever i try to increment a certain variable in my main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gb/gb.h>
#include "convert.h"
#include "display.h"
#include "input.h"
#include "functions.h"
#include "interpreter.h"

unsigned char cnt[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};//cnt is short for counters
unsigned char k = 0;
unsigned char running = 1;

unsigned char memory[2048];
unsigned char code[2048];

int main()
{
    Clear_mem();
    Clear_code();

    while(running == 1) {
        display(cnt[0],cnt[1],cnt[2],cnt[3],cnt[4]);
        printf("cnt[0] = %d\n", cnt[0]);
        cnt[0]++;//turns into -17918
        printf("Press Start To Enter   Next Character\n");
        waitpad(J_START);
        code[k] = input();
        interpret(code[k]);
        k++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

cnt[0] turns into -17918
can anyone see any problem that would cause it to behave this way?

Comment: Isitnoindentationday?

Comment: Why do you think `cnt[0]` is `-17918`? Type of variable is `unsigned char`, it cannot be negative.

Comment: this is why i am so confused i print out what cnt[0] is after its been incremented and its prints out -17918 and before its 1!

Comment: Try to post some minimal code that can be compiled by us. Just by doing this, you might actually find by yourself what the issue is.

Comment: Let's fix one thing first: use `%u` instead of `%d` for printing `unsigned char`. Using `%d` might give you wrong output, if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(unsigned char)`.

Comment: @user694733 do you think it is possible to have sizeof(int) == sizeof(unsigned char) in compliance with the C standard?

Comment: @helleye Yes. Sizes must be `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int)`. `char` must be 8 bits or more. If `char` is 16 bits, then it possible for `short` and `int` be 16 bits too. OP mentions something about the gameboy, and I am not sure if this applies to that system.

Comment: Indeed, I am working on a platform now with `CHAR_BIT == 16` and `sizeof(int) == sizeof(unsigned char)`.

Comment: I agree with both of you. I was again checking the standard and realized that actually char could be more than 1 byte and int is at least two bytes. @Vicky I am curious what platform are you working on?

Comment: A small suggestion: print the value of `k` as well, and let us know if the problem happens as soon as it becomes larger than 2047 (or sometime after that).

Comment: @helleye, a CSR BC05 Bluecore chip which has a XAP core.

Answer (score 1):

You ask if anyone sees a problem, well - yes, here is a problem:

```
unsigned char k = 0;
unsigned char running = 1;
unsigned char code[2048];

while(running == 1) {
    code[k] = input();
    k++;
}
```

If `k >= 2048`, then `code[k] = ...` will cause a memory-override.

After a memory-override, pretty much anything can happens (undefined behavior).

Having said that, the value of `k` can be larger than 2047 only if `CHAR_BIT` is larger than 11.

Add `#include <limits.h>` to your program and make sure that `CHAR_BIT` is not larger than 11.

Comment: How will declaring `int k` solve the problem of k being >= 2048?

Comment: @helleye: LOL, I was concentrating on the `CHAR_BIT` issue (whether it limited `k` to 255 or not), and by then forgot the initial problem at hand. It most certainly won't solve anything, so I removed that statement on the bottom of the answer (which I added later anyway)... Thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: I saw that there were a lot of edits of your answer, and they were all improvements, but the last one was not ;)

Comment: @helleye: Wow, people see edits??? OMG. I edit every answer of mine about 20 times on average, just rephrasing sentences, correcting grammar, etc. Man, I gotta stop doing it in that case!

Comment: @helleye: A more generalized statement would be 'I gotta quit this SO bad habit of mine'...

Comment: It is not bad when you improve your answer, but it would be better if you take your time and review your answer before submitting it.

Comment: i changed k to a unsigned short

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to an integer, because that's what you're trying to print:

```
printf("cnt[0] = %d\n", (int) cnt[0]);
```

When you're using a variadic function like `printf`, you have to make sure you're passing the right type. Check your compiler warning settings, new compilers can easily detect these kind of problems.

Comment: thanks its just adding 1 now! i never new you had to convert variables like that

Comment: Most of the time you don't need it, because you can simply specify the type in the format string. There is `%c` and `%uc` for characters, but that will display the actual (ascii) character, and you want to print a number.

Comment: When calling `printf`, each integer argument which is shorter than 4 bytes is expanded to 4 bytes. Your answer doesn't quite explain why the byte value of `0x80` (the first negative value encountered) would be expanded into the 4-byte value of `0xFFFFBA02` (by "4 bytes" I actually mean `sizeof(int)`, which can be 2 bytes on some rare platforms).

Comment: Like barak manos, I am baffled as to why your compiler didn't automatially promote the `char` argument to `int`.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I have no idea either. `%ud` should work. and unless you're on some strange architecture (I've never heard of) `%d` should work to (because in both forms the actual representation is the same). As a sidenote: why SO doesn't let me downvote my own answer? :)

Comment: _"thanks its just adding 1 now!"_ It was just adding 1 the whole time, but now you're printing its actual value.

Comment: I have a feeling that the real problem lies in `code[k] = ...`, which at some point causes memory override (as soon as `k >= 2048` to be more accurate).

Comment: Normally, an `unsigned char` should be promoted to `int` anyways, right? Unless `sizeof(unsigned char) == sizeof(int)`, in which case it'd be promoted to `unsigned int`. In that case, could you also just use `%hhu` as the format and avoid the cast?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the **character** value of your **character** variable you should print it like this:

```
printf("cnt[0] = %c\n", cnt[0]);
```

If you print it using `%d` the expansion of the character to a size of int could be negative for characters over half a character's size (0x80 and up).

If you insist on printing it as an int cast the variable like this:

```
printf("cnt[0] = %d\n", (int)cnt[0]);
```